# При вызове метода возвращает null

Tags: java

Вот первый класс:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Game {
    private int srtLoc;
    private String result;
    private boolean tri;
    private ArrayList<Game> Games = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game newGame = new Game();
        newGame.setList(1, -1); //создаём и добавляем объекты в 'Games'
        newGame.removeMe(); //удаляем объект по заданному индексу
        Game2 literatic = new Game2();
        literatic.m1(); //создаём и добавляем объекты в 'MyFavourite'
        favourite(); //выводим сведения о моих любимых играх
    }
    private String setList (int a, int b) {
        if (a == 1) {
            Game one = new Game();
            Game two = new Game();
            Game three = new Game();
            Game four = new Game();
            Game five = new Game();
            Games.add(one);
            Games.add(two);
            Games.add(three);
            Games.add(four);
            Games.add(five);
            outPrint(); //показываем какой объект в ячейку с каким индексом был доставлен
            System.out.println("В ArrayList 'Games' сейчас " + Games.size() + " объектов(а)!");
            System.out.println("'Games' пуст? " + Games.isEmpty());
        }
        if (a == 2) {
            for (Game GoodGame : Games) {
                int rob = Games.indexOf(GoodGame);
                if (b == rob) {
                    b++;
                    result = Integer.toString(b);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (b > Games.size() || b < 0) {
                System.out.println("В 'Games' нет таких объектов");
                result = "ничего";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void removeMe() {
        String resulting = null;
        String userInputing = getUserInput("Какой объект вы хотите удалить?");
        if (userInputing != null) {
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInputing);
            resulting = checkYourself(userInput);
        }
        if (resulting != "ничего") {
            System.out.println("Вы удаляете " + "'Game " + resulting + "'");
            System.out.println("В ArrayList 'Games' сейчас " + Games.size() + " объектов(а)!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы " + resulting + " не удаляете.");
            System.out.println("В ArrayList 'Games' сейчас " + Games.size() + " объектов(а)!");
        }
    }
    private String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.println(prompt + "   ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if (inputLine.length() == 0) return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:" + e);
        }
        return inputLine.toLowerCase();
    }
    private String checkYourself(int userInput1) {
        for (Game srt : Games) {
            srtLoc = Games.indexOf(srt);
            if (srtLoc == userInput1) {
                tri = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        result = setList(2, userInput1);
        if (tri) {
            Games.remove(srtLoc);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void outPrint() {
        int loc = 1;
        for (Game wer : Games) {
            int x = Games.indexOf(wer);
            System.out.println("Я добавляю в 'Games' объект Game " + loc + " по индексу " + x);
            loc++;
        }
    }
    private static void favourite() {
        Game2 right = new Game2();
        System.out.println("Мои любимые игры: " + right.getNameToGame2(0) + ", " + right.getNameToGame2(1) + ", " + right.getNameToGame2(2));
    }
}
```

А вот второй класс:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Game2 extends Game {
    private String name;
    private String myName;
    private ArrayList<Game2> MyFavourite = new ArrayList<>();
    public void m1() {
        Game2 first = new Game2();
        Game2 second = new Game2();
        Game2 third = new Game2();
        MyFavourite.add(first);
        MyFavourite.add(second);
        MyFavourite.add(third);
        first.setName("RimWord");
        second.setName("Diablo 2");
        third.setName("Космические рейнджеры 2");
    }
    private void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    public String getNameToGame2(int h) {
        for (Game2 j : MyFavourite) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            if (h == MyFavourite.indexOf(j)) {
                myName = j.getName();
                break;
            }
        }
        return myName;
    }    
}
```

После вызова `favourite();` выдаёт в списке моих любимых игр null, null, null. Даже не выводит "Test", я так понял JVM в `for(Game2 j : MyFavourite) { }` вообще не заходит, хотя остальная часть программы ведёт себя хорошо (компилятор пропускает ни говоря ни слова). Этот код не особо важен, я сделал его, чтобы получше разобраться с функциями ArrayList, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Помогите пожалуйста! (Программирую в Java примерно неделю, знания крохотные, поэтому не серчайте, что код прямолинейный и не совсем ООП, я только учусь).

[image: Вот, что JVM выдаёт в конце концов.]

Comment: После вызова `Game2 right = new Game2();` нужно вызвать `m1();` , а потом уже выводить в консоль. При создании объекта `new Game2()` поле `MyFavourite` пустое, поэтому и выводится null

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ правильный, следует его оформить как ответ и отметить как правильный.

Comment: И да, у Вас не выведет имена игр ибо вы их инициализируете после записи в коллекцию